# Sending Json using Jquery $.post and getting the result back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I cannot send this Json To another PHP page...Do i have to Stringify it or what???My aim is to Inert Email into database and get validation message back...If it is already in database i should get the validation message back and do not insert it into database if it is in there already.
The page where my form is located is this one...
Index.php

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


     $("#emailForm").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var emailValue = form.find("#email").val();
        var url = form.attr("action");

        var posting = $.post( url, { email : emailValue });

        posting.done(function( data ){
            $("#email_approved_message").empty();
            $("#email_approved_message").html(data);
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<form  id="emailForm" method="POST" action="petme.php">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$" required>
    <br>
    <span class="error_form" id="email_error_message"></span>
    <span class="approved_form" id="email_approved_message"></span>
    <br> 
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Pošalji">
</form>
```

This is my petme.php page where i should validate email input value.I cannot get back validation message from function ServerValidationMessage,i need to get that string back and show it in span with id=email_approved_message!!!

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
include_once("../app/modules_bl/emailBL.class.php");

$email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
$EmailBL = new EmailBL();
$ObjectsFromBM = $EmailBL->GetEmail();

foreach ($ObjectsFromBM as $ObjectFromBM)
{
    $arrayofEmails[]= $ObjectFromBM->GetEMAIL_BM();
}

$returnedMsg = ServerValidationMessage($email);
$validatedEmail = array("validationMessage" => "$returnedMsg");

print(json_encode($validatedEmail));

function ServerValidationMessage($email)
{
    if(is_array($email) || is_numeric($email) || is_bool($email) || is_float($email) || is_file($email) || is_dir($email) || is_int($email))
    {
        return $emailfalseMsg;
    }
    else
    {
        $email= trim(strtolower($email));
        $emailtrueMsg = "Uspešno ste uneli email i prijavili se na naš newslettter!";
        $emailfalseMsg = "Morate uneti ispravnu email adresu!";
        $emptyemailfieldMsg = "Unesite email!";                    
        $emailduplicatedMsg = "Vi ste se već prijavili na naš newletter sa ovom email adresom!";

        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false && $email != "")
        {
            $EmailBL = new EmailBL();
            $ObjectsFromBM = $EmailBL->GetEmail();

            foreach ($ObjectsFromBM as $ObjectFromBM)
            {
                $arrayofEmails[]= $ObjectFromBM->GetEMAIL_BM();
            }
            if(in_array($email, $arrayofEmails) && isset($arrayofEmails))
            {
                return $emailduplicatedMsg;
            }
            else
            {
                $EmailBL->InsertEmail();
                return $emailtrueMsg;
            }
        }
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false && $email != "")
        {
            $pattern = '/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD';
            return (preg_match($pattern, $email) === 1) ? $emailtrueMsg : $emailfalseMsg;
        }
        if($email == "")
        {
            return $emptyemailfieldMsg;
        }
    }        
}
```

?>

Comment: what exactly is the problem? is `$_POST['email']` not set?

Comment: You are not sending JSON.  By default, if you give $.get/$.post/$.ajax a {} for the data, it will turn it into a query string.

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong with the way you are sending the data. Please provide a more specific and detailed problem description

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` and check what actually is sent to the server.

Comment: _sidenote:_ `$emailfalseMsg` won't be defined when you try to return it in `if (is_number($email)...)`

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Instead of fetching _all_ the emails from the database (twice, no less) and put them into an array, just query the database to see if you find it. If you don't want that, you can at least check if it exists in the result in the foreach directly, instead of creating extra arrays with the emails and use `in_array()`.

Comment: This line `return $emailfalseMsg;` needs to have a value set for `$emailfalseMsg` before you run that line !!!

Comment: So you're saying that `$returnedMsg` is not what you expect?

Comment: The problem is that i need to get return value of the function ServerValidationMessage into a span which has the id email_approved_message id="email_approved_message".As you see my ServerValidationMessage function deals with server side validation i cannot seem to write that message into span with id="email_approved_message"...

Comment: Side note3: If you are putting a variable into anything, and only the variable... don't wrap it in double quotes like you have here: `array("validationMessage" => "$returnedMsg");` ... this is more proper: `array("validationMessage" => $returnedMsg);`

Comment: _Suggestion 2:_ The first `if`-statement will all the variable type checks are pretty unnecessary. Just check it with `filter_var()` directly.

Comment: `$("#email_approved_message").html(data);`  You're injecting the entire JSON response into your HTML.  You probably only want a specific value, such as `data.validationMessage`.

Comment: _sidenote4:_  `&& $email != ""` is not necessary

Comment: @Jeff ah ok mate i have noticed that and i have moved this block of code $email= trim(strtolower($email));
        $emailtrueMsg = "Uspešno ste uneli email i prijavili se na naš newslettter!";
        $emailfalseMsg = "Morate uneti ispravnu email adresu!";
        $emptyemailfieldMsg = "Unesite email!";                    
        $emailduplicatedMsg = "Vi ste se već prijavili na naš newletter sa ovom email adresom!"; above first if statement in ServerValidationMessage function Thank you!!!

Comment: @Taplar aham so it is processed as string is this a good practice or what?Thank you very much!!!

Comment: It's processing it as a query string (ex.  ?key1=value1&key2=value2).  It's not good/bad practice.  However, it is expected behavior.

Comment: Suggestion 2: The first if-statement will all the variable type checks are pretty unnecessary. Just check it with filter_var() directly. – Magnus Eriksson 10 mins ago<< i have deleted those statements thank you!!!

Comment: Magnus Eriksson 15 mins ago<<<  So you think something like this i have a Table: newsletter
Columns:
ID_NEWSLETTER int(11) AI PK 
EMAIL varchar(254) 
INSERT_DATE varchar(30) 
ID_STATUS int(11) so a query for that would be SELECT ID_NEWSLETTER,n.EMAIL
FROM NEWSLETTER AS N
WHERE n.EMAIL = 'value of the email input'; Do you think something like this to avoid fetching all emails from database mate?